# Sum returns null in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to subtract two value while querying the data from the database for creating a graph. but it always return null when i try the code

```html
downtime = Ticket.by_month.where(:sla => true).sum("restore_time - start_time")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `null` values in `restore_time` or `start_time`. In SQL, `null - X` and `X - null` are `null` for all `X` as are `null + X` and `X + null`. That means that a `null` value in any of your `restore_time` or `start_time` columns will turn the entire sum into `null`.

You could ignore the rows with `null`s:

```
Ticket.by_month
      .where(:sla => true)
      .where.not(:restore_time => nil)
      .where.not(:start_time => nil)
      .sum('restore_time - start_time')
```

or convert them to something that makes sense in your context:

```
Ticket.by_month
      .where(:sla => true)
      .sum('coalesce(restore_time, something_sensible) - coalesce(start_time, something_sensible)')
```

or perhaps:

```
Ticket.by_month
      .where(:sla => true)
      .sum('coalesce(restore_time - start_time, something_sensible)')
```

Where `something_sensible` would be what you want to use in place of `null`s, this value would of course have to have the same type as the first argument to the `coalesce` calls.

Comment: This helped solve my problem! Thanks. TIL

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
restore_time = Ticket.by_month.where(:sla => true).sum("restore_time")
start_time = Ticket.by_month.where(:sla => true).sum("start_time")
downtime = restore_time - start_time
```

Comment: sadly the data  return with one value which is not multiple data which group by month